# Не срабатывает распаковка файла

Tags: c#

Вот небольшая програмка, которая берет большой файл, режет его на части, помещает части в очередь, из очереди кусочки сжимаются и записываются в файл, далее метод распаковки, берет файл и распаковывает его, но файл почему то не распаковывается. Подскажите что не так, заранее спасибо

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace read_to_buffer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
        static string outFile = @"d:\Test1.gz";
        private static string outdecompres = @"d:\Black WidowDecompress.m4a";
        private static string ErrorMessage;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _path = @"d:\Black Widow.m4a";

            //Queue<byte[]> bqQueue = Readd(_path);// просто очередь с частями файла
            //Queue<byte[]> bqcompres = new Queue<byte[]>();// очередь компрессия

            //int count = bqQueue.Count;

            //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            //{
            //    bqcompres.Enqueue(Compres(bqQueue.Dequeue()));
            //    WriteFile(bqcompres.Dequeue());
            //}

            Unpack(outFile, outdecompres);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static Queue<byte[]> Readd(string _path)
        {
            using (var fsSource = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // читаю части файла
                int numBytesToRead = 1024 * 1024;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytesToRead];
                Queue<byte[]> qw = new Queue<byte[]>();

                int numBytesReaded;

                do
                {
                    int numBytesRead = 0;
                    numBytesReaded = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                    if (numBytesReaded > 0)
                    {
                        qw.Enqueue(bytes);
                    }

                } while (numBytesReaded > 0);

                return qw;
            }
        } // чтение из файла и разбиенние на блоки

        public static byte[] Compres(byte[] inputData) // компрес
        {
            using (var compressIntoMs = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var gzs = new BufferedStream(new GZipStream(compressIntoMs,
                    CompressionMode.Compress), BUFFER_SIZE))
                {
                    gzs.Write(inputData, 0, inputData.Length);
                }
                return compressIntoMs.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static bool Unpack(string originalFile, string unpackedFile)
        {
            GZipStream gzip = null;
            FileStream readStream = null;
            FileStream writeStream = null;

            try
            {
                readStream = new FileStream(originalFile, FileMode.Open);
                writeStream = new FileStream(unpackedFile, FileMode.Create);
                gzip = new GZipStream(readStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                int size = 1024 * 1024; //размер буфера для обмена между потоками
                byte[] unpackbuf = new byte[size]; //буфер                
                int count = 0; //для хранения фактически прочитанных байт

                //пишем распакованные данные по кускам
                do
                {
                    count = gzip.Read(unpackbuf, 0, size); //читаем кусками размером size
                    if (count > 0) //если данные есть
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(unpackbuf, 0, count); //пишем фактически 
                                                                //прочитанное кол-во байт
                    }
                } while (count > 0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (readStream != null) readStream.Close();
                if (writeStream != null) writeStream.Close();
                if (gzip != null) gzip.Close();
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message;

                return false;
            }

            gzip.Close();
            readStream.Close();
            writeStream.Close();
            return true;
        }

        public static void WriteFile(byte[] dataas)
        {
            var outStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

            int count = 1024 * 1024;
            int ofset = 0;
            do
            {
                outStream.Write(dataas, ofset, count);
            } while (ofset > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы берете куски одинаковой длины и сжимаете их. После сжатия куски получаются **разной** длины! А вы при распаковке опять читаете куски той же самой длины, что неправильно.

Comment: И как тогда сделать, на куски я делать должен потому что файл может быть большим, как мне можно поступить, и странно при сжатии файл получается большим, то есть файл весит 32 мегабайта, а при сжатии таким методом получается 64,странно

Comment: В любом случае ваш алгоритм только для маленьких файлов, целиком умещающихся в памяти: ведь вы сперва помещаете его кусками в очередь. Так что, во-первых, уберите обе очереди. Читаете кусок из первого потока, сжимаете, помещаете во второй поток. Во-вторых, перед каждым сжатым куском пишите его размер. При распаковке, соответственно, сперва читаете размер куска, потом читаете нужное количество байт.

Comment: При сжатии пиши сначала номер блока, потом его размер и данные самого блока. При распаковке читай номер, размер блока и нужное количество байт, вставлять соответственно данный блок нужно будет по порядку его номера. И очередь должна быть ограничена по размеру чтобы вся память не израсходовалась. А программа не должна быть многопоточной? `Veeam Software` на потоках заморочены.

Comment: Ребята спасибо за комментарии, Вы пишите Во-вторых, перед каждым сжатым куском пишите его размер. а как мне организовать хранение этих данных. Вот сжал кусок файла,  записал его размер и порядковый номер, где это хранить? Да программа должна быть много поточной.

Comment: дык в файл по порядку и пиши. сначала номер, затем размер и сами сжатые данные

Comment: то есть к блоку сжатому добавляем в начало 4 байта это номер блока, и еще 4 байта это размер, а затем идут уже сами сжатые данные, и потом также читаем?

Comment: Номер блока нужен только в том случае, если будет многопоточность. Сейчас её в принципе нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  да про комментарии понял, а про многопоточность, мне нужно каждый блок сжимать и записывать в файл, независимо от другого. Для этого и нужны номера блоков,  и наверное использовать шаблон для многопоточности думаю,Producer/Consumer